# condaでの環境構築に関して、複数作る時の無駄なことについて（容量的なところで質問です。）

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

標記に関し質問させてください。

```
conda create -n 環境名
```

にて複数環境構築しているのですが、

毎回、

```
conda create -n 環境名　python=hogehoge-version anaconda
```

を基本として、パッケージの追加をしています。

自分は独学で日曜プログラマーで周りにこういった場合の勘所というか、暗黙知のような、tips的な、ものを聞ける相手がおらず、、質問させていただいております。

---

質問：
・このとき、anacondaが毎回インストールされている気がするのですが、これは容量を圧迫しつづけますか？

・容量を圧迫しつづけるならもう少しうまい方法があれば知りたく、condaのドキュメントを読んだのですが基礎的な使い方がメインのようだったので、何かここを読め、みたいなところがあれば教えていただけるとありがたいです。

上記二点、ご教示いただければ幸いです。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: anacondaを利用する前提の質問、という認識でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: そうです！しかしながら、そのanacondaの認識もひとまずいれておけばいいのかな？というくらいで全ての環境に突っ込んでいるので、容量が圧迫されているような気がしてきて、質問致しました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ・このとき、anacondaが毎回インストールされている気がするのですが、これは容量を圧迫しつづけますか？

はい。実行するたびに、その時に利用できる最新版のAnacondaがインストールされるはずので、容量を圧迫していると思います。

> ・容量を圧迫しつづけるならもう少しうまい方法があれば知りたく

仮想環境が利用する容量を減らしたい、ということであれば、以下のようにすると良いのではないでしょうか。

- 使わなくなった仮想環境を`conda remove --name 環境名 --all`で削除する
- `conda create`するときに、anacondaで一式インストールするのではなく、個別にパッケージをインストールする

何回も個別にパッケージをインストールするのが面倒であれば、以下のようにしてもいいかと。

- よく使うパッケージをインストール済みの仮想環境を1つ作成する
- それを用途ごとに`conda create --name 元の環境名 --clone 環境名`でクローンする
- 用途に応じたパッケージを追加する

なお、以下も参考になると思います。
* [Anacondaで仮想環境を作るときに役立つTips集｜はやぶさの技術ノート](https://cpp-learning.com/anaconda_venv_tips/)
* [【初心者向け】Anacondaで仮想環境を作ってみる - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ozaki_physics/items/985188feb92570e5b82d)

Comment: ありがとうございます！リンク先もとても参考になりました！